# How to use virt-manager with LVM? Should I?

Tags: partitioning, encryption, virtualization, lvm, kvm-virtualization

I'm new to LVM but I think it has advantages when used in virt-manager. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think it's easier to resize the disks of my VMs with it. And also they occupy only the size they use, so I can have an SSD with 128gb but lots of VMs with maximum capacity 128gb but they all can use less than that.

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 with LUKS in LVM mode. However, the LVM volume `root` now occupies almost all of my SSD. It should occupy only a little so I can create new volumes to use on my VMs. Am I right? If so, then how can I do this on the installation?

Comment: The benefits you mentioned (dynamic sizing, use only blocks that are needed) you get by using sparse qcow2 files as well (the default) and you'll avoid a lot of custom setup for your LVM to work well with virt-manager (e.g. custom apparmor rules to allow those paths, and ensuring that libvirt can manage them)

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt for me, when I create a cow2 file with 100gb of size, it already uses 100gb of size on my SSD. What am I doing wrong? I simply create them with virt-manager

Comment: That is odd, could you try if that is only the case if you do so through some UI/Tool (then we need to discuss those defaults) or on your system in general (might depend on FS configuration then). If you run `qemu-img create -f qcow2 foo.qcow2 100M` that would be a 100M disk that initially has ~193k as seen with `ll -h foo.qcow2`.